# What wrong in this code?

Tags: asp.net, jquery

Here i have 2 list boxes ,when i click add button then items should be added to second list box in asp.net using jquery.

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ListBoxExample.aspx.cs" Inherits="ListBoxExample" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Adding,removing elements from First Listbox to Second Listbox</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .lstbx1
        {
            font-family: Verdana;
            font-size: medium;
            font-style: normal;
            background-color: Aqua;
            height: auto;
            width: auto;
        }
        .lstbx2
        {
            font-family: Verdana;
            font-size: medium;
            font-style: normal;
            background-color: Lime;
            height: auto;
            width: auto;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.1.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Move_Elements() {
            $("#lstbx1").appendTo("#lstbx2");
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:ListBox ID="lstbx1" runat="server" CssClass="lstbx1" SelectionMode="Multiple">
                        <asp:ListItem>One</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Two</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Three</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Four</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Five</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Six</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Seven</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:ListBox>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:ListBox ID="lstbx2" runat="server" CssClass="lstbx2"></asp:ListBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnadd" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClientClick="Move_Elements();" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnremove" runat="server" Text="Remove" OnClientClick="" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do in Move_Elements()? That is not quite right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Move_Elements() {
        var originalList = $("#<%= this.lstbx1.ClientID %>");
        var items = $('option', originalList);
        var targetList = $("#<%= this.lstbx2.ClientID %>");
        items/*.clone()*/.appendTo(targetList);
    }

</script>
```

[working example](http://jsfiddle.net/XuWrA/)

**edit:**
anyway, i just want to warn you, that you are not able to access the items in code-behind, because these are serialized in viewstate and are not taken from the actual rendered control.
as a result: if you add n items with javascript and have one of these newly-added items selected as `selectedItem` in the ui, the asp.net-engine will fail to map the `selectedValue` at server-side to an item of the box, because it does not have these items in the viewstate!

Comment: here am getting an like "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected".Could you please help me?

Comment: @enjoyprogramming: still getting this exception?

Comment: Yah am still getting this exception

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Move_Elements() {
   $('select[id=lstbx1] option').appendTo('#List2');
}
```

Comment: -, this wont't work, because you have to use `<%= this.lstbx1.ClientID %>` to get the correct id (this is asp.net specific!)

Comment: ok...i don't know about asp.net..i am just telling a jquery way to do this...it's his job to think about correct id but i have up voted you for your answer. :)

Comment: you should add a sentence for `getting correct ids` - until this point your solution is invalid - sorry pal! but your jquery-part is correct, indeed!

Comment: While am clicking the button the page is refreshing.I am not getting the exact output

Comment: page is refreshing..ok are you submitting any form on click of that button?

Comment: Yes am submitting form called "form1".

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.1.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Move_Elements() {
        $(".lstbx1").children().appendTo(".lstbx2");
    }
</script>
...
<asp:Button ID="btnadd" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClientClick="Move_Elements();return false;" />
```